# How to draw in latex an equilateral triangle on the x and yaxis with bottom left corner at (−1, −2) and side length 3

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I understand how to make a standard triangle with coordinates on the x and yaxis but I can't figure out how to make the triangle an equilateral triangle with side length 3.
I have this but it's just a standard triangle with coordinates I came up with and not the length 3 I need.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-3,0) -- (3,0);
\draw (0,-3) -- (0,3);
\draw [line width=1.5pt] (-1,-2) -- (2,-2) -- (0.5,1) -- cycle; \end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using polar coordinates `(\ang:\dist)` where `\ang` is the angle with respect to horizontal and `\dist` is the distance.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-3,0) -- (3,0);
\draw (0,-3) -- (0,3);
\draw[very thick] (-1,-2) -- +(0:3) -- +(60:3) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Triangle]

Comment: how handy the TikZ operation `+` ! Another way is  `\draw (-1,-2) -- +(0:3) --([turn]120:3) -- cycle;` or `\draw (-1,-2) -- ++(0:3) --++(120:3) -- cycle;` however using `+` is simpler

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to TeX.SX!

The height of an equilateral triangle is `0.5 * sqrt(3) * x` where `x` is the side length. Or you can use trigonometrics using `x * sin(60)` (in degrees). Having this and since the bottom left corner of your triangle is at `(-1,-2)`, you need to shift the result by `(-0.5,-2)`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-3,0) -- (3,0);
\draw (0,-3) -- (0,3);
\draw [line width=1.5pt] (-1,-2) -- (2,-2) -- (0.5,{0.5*sqrt(3)*3-2}) -- cycle; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-3,0) -- (3,0);
\draw (0,-3) -- (0,3);
\draw [line width=1.5pt] (-1,-2) -- (2,-2) -- (0.5,{3*sin(60)-2}) -- cycle; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Both yield:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TikZ` with a rotation of B around A and you can use `tkz-euclide`

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\tkzDefPoints{-1/-2/A,2/-2/B}
\tkzDefTriangle[equilateral](A,B) \tkzGetPoint{C}
\tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For a fan of the classics:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
  \draw[blue, opacity=0.5, name path=ref1] (-1,-2) circle [radius=3cm];
  \draw[blue, opacity=0.5, name path=ref2] (2,-2) circle [radius=3cm];
  \path[name intersections={of=ref1 and ref2}]
    (intersection-1) coordinate (A)
    (intersection-2) coordinate (B);
\end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
\draw[thick] (-1,-2) -- (2,-2) -- (A)-- cycle;% testing is possible but painful
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]